# Macbook Air os 10.9.5

Tags: password, keychain, error

So I get an error message saying "Keychain "login" cannot be found to store "551961960"" and when I get to keychain access and try to repair using the keychain first aid thing and I get "Keychain Access wants to use the "Local items" keychain" and asks for the password. I try my admin password and that doesn't help. I don't know the password. Help!